# Reading Ble device Battery value

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, batterylevel

I'm trying to read the battery level from a bluetooth ble device using CoreBluetooth and GATT. I successfully connect to the device, I also get the right list of services as shown in the debug below :

```
didDiscoverServices:(
"<CBService: 0x170273440, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>",
"<CBService: 0x170273700, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1803>",
"<CBService: 0x170273740, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1802>",
"<CBService: 0x170273780, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1804>",
"<CBService: 0x1702737c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Battery>",
"<CBService: 0x170273800, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Heart Rate>",
"<CBService: 0x170273840, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFF0>",
"<CBService: 0x170273880, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFF3>")
```

Obviously the one we want here has the "Battery" uuid. It has only one service which is :

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1700bf500, UUID = Battery Level, properties = 0x12, value = <64>, notifying = NO>
```

So I save that characteristic into a variable to later reading. Then I call "readValueForCharacteristic" and wait for "didUpdateValueForCharacteristic" to bring me the update. Everything works fine until that point.
The value seems wrong. It's just 1 bit which equals <64> and whatever I do it never changes.
I always get 100% while doing :

```
Byte *rsp = (Byte*)[value bytes];
NSString percent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhu",rsp[0]];
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: 0x64 in hex is 100 in decimal. Looks ok to me. What else did you expect ?

Comment: Yup, but the value seems not to change. It stays at 64. Always. That's why I'm thinking something's wrong or I don't get the right value.

Comment: There might be an issue with the hardware itself. I'll dig into it.

Comment: @Morgan  Did you found any solution to this?

Comment: @TechFanatic not since the day I posted this. I ended up alerting my users based on my ble devices estimated discharge time...